# Moving files based on extensions into sub-folders

Tags: batch-file, move, directory

I'm looking a for loop that will go into the sub directories and move file with extensions mp4 and flv into a folder call Media.

```
  Folder structure is as follows: 
  Folder 1 (Parent) (Where bat file would go)
    Folder 1 Sub (First Sub-folder)
      Media (Folder)            
      File_Name.Mp4
      File_Name.flv
    Folder 2 Sub (Second Sub-folder)
      Media (Folder)            
      File_Name.Mp4
      File_Name.flv
    Folder 3 Sub (Third Sub-folder)
      Media (Folder)            
      File_Name.Mp4
      File_Name.flv
      And so on..... I have about 1100 sub-folders in Folder 1 (parent folder
```

Thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

change the start folder `Folder 1 (Parent)` if necessary and try:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /r "Folder 1 (Parent)" %%i in (*.mp4 *.flv) do (
    echo("%%~pi"|findstr /ri ".\\Media\\.$" >nul|| echo move "%%~fi" "%%~dpiMedia\%%~nxi"
)
```

Comment: You'd better quote the %%~pi in case of & characters.

Comment: I realised that it's not necessary in a %% variable.  It was just a force of habit.  :)

Comment: `%%a` get kind of delayed expansion :)

Answer (score 2):

This is designed to process all the 1st level folders in the parent, and move the mp4 and flv files into a folder called media that is inside the first level folder.

It is untested.  Test it on some sample folders.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /ad /b ') do (
pushd "%%a"
md Media 2>nul
for %%z in (mp4 flv) do move *.%%z Media 
popd
)
```